# How to get Vim to interpret only printable ASCII characters?

Tags: linux, vim, ascii

What I want is pretty simple, so hopefully the fix is pretty simple.
I want whatever file I open in VIM to treat each byte as a low-ASCII character.

I want the character to be displayed normally if the character fits one of the following criteria:

- It has a graphical representation (so, it isn't a number, letter, or punctuation)
- It is a newline, space, or tab character (horizontal tab, not vtab)

Otherwise, I want each byte to be displayed in Vim's usual format for an unprintable binary byte (e.g. `<02>`, `^H`, `^@`).

Note: This question is similar / related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219875/how-to-get-vim-to-show-a-byte-by-byte-representation-of-file-data), but I'm asking it again here because it's broader, it belongs here rather than SO, and that question didn't have any satisfactory answers.

Using `xxd` for this kind of thing feels like overkill.

Comment: Why isn't the `binary` mode answer to that question (presently the last one) satisfactory?

Comment: The BOM is displayed as a single, two-byte character `<feff>`, which is drastically incorrect on a number of levels (the BOM is three bytes so it's wrong about the length, as per this question I want to be able to modify each byte individually so it's representation is unhelpful, and the BOM is actually `0xefbbbf`; it doesn't even contain `0xff` so the representation is misleading).

Comment: Tried to run Vim as `LANG=C; vim`? That should disable all upper ASCII.

Comment: @jcoppens No dice, but it's a good suggestion.

Comment: What do you want Vim to do with bytes that are not representable in ASCII at all? The suggestion to use `:e ++enc=latin1` in the linked question is the approach I would use, but that shows some character for bytes with a value requiring 8 bits to represent, whereas ASCII is a 7-bit system and therefore cannot possibly represent these characters at all. If you really have a file with only ASCII-representable bytes, you can try reading the file in an ASCII encoding (e.g. on Windows, cp20127) but that will give a conversion error if there's something like a BOM in the file.

Comment: @Ben That works okay, although it'd be nicer to actually be able to see the byte values. I know when I open binaries it'll often simply give me `<XX>` (where the Xs are hexadecimal digits) highlighted in blue for characters it doesn't know. Ideally, that would be the case for all octets that aren't letters, (a subset of) whitespace, and punctuation.